# Markdown Program with SmartyPants

Tags: markdown

I use markdown for quite a lot now. Is there a standalone program (like "markdown" or "discount") that also supports smartypants. I use `--` all over the place and I really would like to see some ndashes there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) supports smartypants with the `--smart` option.

If you like a java program, you can compile [Pegdown](https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown) which also have a `SMARTYPANTS` extension.

Comment: This works, although it breaks up the HTML tags very weird: `<p \n >` …